# How to use Xon-Xoff protocol with Java?

Tags: java

I try to development a code for print a fiscal ticket.
I use Java (programmation language) an XON-XOFF with protocol to use to print ticket.

So I have write this code:

```
    public SerialPortHandler(String portaCOM){
        log = new MyLog4J();
        try {
            this.connect(portaCOM);
            this.provaScontrino();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.logStackTrace(e);
        }
    }

    public void connect(String portName) throws IOException {
        try {
            // Obtain a CommPortIdentifier object for the port you want to open
            CommPortIdentifier portId =
                CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
            log.information("apro porta seriale");
            //System.out.println("apro porta seriale");
            // Get 
            serialPort =
                (SerialPort) portId.open("Demo application", 5000);
            // Set the parameters of the connection.
            setSerialPortParameters();
            log.information("settaggio porta terminato");

        } catch (NoSuchPortException e) {
            log.logStackTrace(e);
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (PortInUseException e) {
            log.logStackTrace(e);
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.logStackTrace(e);
            serialPort.close();
            throw e;
        }
    }

   public void provaScontrino(){
        try {
            outStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
            //inStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
            log.information("output acquisito ora provo a stampare uno scontrino");
            String messageString = "j";
            outStream.write(messageString.getBytes()); 
            //messageString = "'PANTALONE'10H1R";
            //outStream.write(messageString.getBytes()); 
            messageString = "\"MAGLIA\"3*100H1P";
            outStream.write(messageString.getBytes()); 
            messageString = "1T";
            outStream.write(messageString.getBytes());
            messageString = "J";
            outStream.write(messageString.getBytes());
            log.information("scontrino stampato ora apro il cassetto");
            apriCassetto();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.logStackTrace(e);
        }
    }
```

So whit this code I think to have a non fiscal ticket with "3 MAGLIE" but I received a ticket like this:

```
DITTA S.R.L.
  NAME OF CITY
   P.IVA

                 EURO
Operatore 12
Reparto 1         0,00
TOTALE EURO       0,00
CONTANTI          0,00

14/10/14 10:55     SF.4
```

Can we help me?

Reguards

Comment: To get an answer you should propably explain what do you expect (what is "3 MAGLIE" anyway) and what printer model you are using.

Comment: The code messageString = "\"MAGLIA\"3*100H1P"; I use it for print on ticket the name of Articles.